# Strange Chrome behaviour after create a new Fabric Canvas

Tags: fabricjs

After I created a new canvas with fabric. elements with absolute or relative position inside a div (also with relative or absolute) are not rendered correctly, including 'range' type inputs  from chrome. Only after I put the mouse hover an object on canvas that these elements go to the right position. In Firefox everything works as expected. Any tips how to solve this?